# Why can I map <M-w> but not <M-r> in gvim?

Tags: vim, keyboard

I successfully defined a mapping to be invoked with `ALT+w` like so `:map <M-w> ....`

Yet, if I try to define a new mapping to be invoked with `ALT+r` like so `:map <M-r> ...` it doesn't work. Instead, the character `ò` (if the mapping is invoked in insert mode) is inserted. This is the same character that is inserted without mappings at all (and also with gvim started with `gvim -u NONE`).

I don't understand why one mapping works and the other doesn't.

**Edit** to answer some quiestions

I am working on a german Windows 7. The current keyboard layout is *English (USA)*

When I press `Alt+w` in insert mode without mapping, I get a `÷`.

Comment: What do you get when you press Alt+w without mapping?

Comment: Also what is your keyboard layout? International English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both mappings works on my machine.

Maybe there is some problem with your mapping command, or it is still being changed by some setting you are using. Despite of using  `u -NONE` you could try some other switches, as `-U` and `-i`; more info on this can be found on [vim faq 36.12](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-36.12). You could also try with `noremap` instead of `map`.

["20.4. I am not able to create a mapping for the  key. What is wrong?"](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-20.4) has some additional suggestions.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the valuable link (20.4 I am not able...) although it didn't help.

Comment: Also using `nnoremap` (in my case> inoremap) instead of `map` did the trick!

Comment: `noremap`can be used for all modes without remap, just as `map`.